# Why is a c++ method which is defined static in a header file not showing up in a symbol table

Tags: c++, linker, verilator

I am trying to compile and link the runtime support code for Verilator (veripool.org).  It builds fine, but for some reason there are a couple of methods which aren't showing up in the pertinent object file, `Verilated::timeunit(int)` and `Verilated::timeprecision(int)`.

Those are ostensibly defined in include/verilated.h:

```
    static int timeunit() VL_MT_SAFE { return Verilated::threadContextp()->timeunit(); }
    static int timeprecision() VL_MT_SAFE { return Verilated::threadContextp()->timeprecision(); }
```

Now, you can see that there is a parameter to both methods of type `int` in the calling function which shows up in the linking step:

```
ld: /home/jon/controlix/src/nuttx/nuttx/staging/libcontrols.a(Vhello_world__ALL.o): in function `Vhello_world::__Vconfigure(Vhello_world__Syms*, bool)':
Vhello_world__ALL.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Verilated::timeunit(int)'
Vhello_world__ALL.cpp:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PLT32 against undefined symbol `Verilated::timeunit(int)'
ld: Vhello_world__ALL.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `Verilated::timeprecision(int)'
Vhello_world__ALL.cpp:(.text+0x20): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PLT32 against undefined symbol `Verilated::timeprecision(int)'
l
```

I have tried changing the method declarations in `verilated.h` to take an int as a parameter even though lack of that should cause a compile-time error, but still those two method declarations don't show up in the symbol table for `verilated.cpp`.  Other methods in the `Verilated::` class show up just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing?*  What it means for a freestanding function to be `static`.

Comment: Those two funcios are not freestanding, AFAICS.  They are definitely methods of the class ```Verilated::```.

Comment: Looking a bit more deeply in the error logs, there's a big red flag here: `hello_world__ALL.cpp`. Are you doing something like a bunch of `#include "some_file.cpp"` in a central cpp file instead of compiling each file individually and linking them together afterwards? That used to be a common-ish practice before LTO was a thing, and it's very easy to cause bizarre and arcane build failures with that pattern.

Comment: *What am I missing?*  What it means for a class static function to be declared (and defined) implicitly inline.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is a c++ method which is defined static in a header file not showing up in a symbol table

Edit: Initially, I assumed that those are non-member functions such as in your quote. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/blob/cf39331d1f48a8438e82bd9a99d6da1db7daf7e2/include/verilated.h), I find that they are member functions. But what I also find is:

> ```
> #ifndef VL_NO_LEGACY
>     // Deprecated
>     static int timeunit() VL_MT_SAFE { return Verilated::threadContextp()->timeunit(); }
>     static int timeprecision() VL_MT_SAFE { return Verilated::threadContextp()->timeprecision(); }
> ```

If the macro `VL_NO_LEGACY` is defined, then those functions won't be defined nor declared. This would explain the lack of their symbols.

---

> `Verilated::timeunit(int)` and `Verilated::timeprecision(int)`.
>
> Those are ostensibly defined in include/verilated.h:
>
> ```
> static int timeunit() VL_MT_SAFE { return Verilated::threadContextp()->timeunit(); }
> static int timeprecision() VL_MT_SAFE { return Verilated::threadContextp()->timeprecision(); }
> ```

No, those are definitely not definitions of the functions declared above. Note the different parameter list.

---

> even though lack of that should cause a compile-time error

Not necessarily. The definition of `static int timeunit()` won't hinder the declaration of `Verilated::timeunit(int)`.

Comment: just about every other method declaration for ```Verilated::``` is declared static, and those are showing up in the symbol table in verilated.cpp.o....

Comment: @JonTaylor If `Verilated` is a class, and those functions are indeed within the scope of `Verilated`, then  `static` has a different meaning for them, because those would be member functions.

Comment: @JonTaylor I checked the header. See edit.

Comment: I fixed the problem - I just ended up moving the function declarations of the two methods to the .cpp file and changing the declarations in the .h file to be normal-type prototypes without a body.  Problem solved.